# Plot within foreach dopar loop

Tags: r, foreach, plot, parallel-processing

Consider the following mock example:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(3)
registerDoParallel(cl)

pdf("mypdf.pdf", width = 8, height = 8)
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE), heights = c(1,1))

result <- foreach(i=1:10000) %dopar% {
    if(i %in% c(5,10,15,20)) {plot(i)}
    i + 2
}

dev.off()
```

This is what I am trying to do: for `i` in `1:10000`, I want to return `i+2`. And, if `i` is equal to 5, 10, 15, 20, I want to plot the point `i` to a pdf. I want all the plots (4 plots) to be in the same pdf.

With a simple `for` loop, this works. However, with parallel computing, it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: R doesn't make it quite so simple for different R sessions (which is what the workers are) to plot to the same PDF file.  You should consider plotting to separate files, and have the master process combine them into a single file afterwards.  That probably requires some extra tools that aren't part of R, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that the cluster workers are completely separate R sessions executing in different processes.  Your code works with a for loop because it executes within by a single process.  With a foreach loop, you're only setting up the PDF graphics device driver in the master process while doing the plotting in the workers.  Instead, you need to do something like this:

```
result <- foreach(i=1:10000) %dopar% {
    if(i %in% c(5,10,15,20)) {
        pdf(sprintf('task_%03d.pdf', i))
        plot(i)
        dev.off()
    }
    i + 2
}
```

Of course, this creates four separate plot files.  If you want to merge them, you'll have to find a tool to do that and call it from the master either in the combine function or after the foreach loop exits.  You may wish to create the plot files in a different format and convert the merged file to a PDF.